# disable redirection to root path / Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache

I have a backend and frontend behind the httpd proxy.
but in the browser, if i visited the front end (reactjs) , then i tried to visit the backend (nodejs), i will be redirect directly to the frontend.
for example,

for the first time, i visited the backend, it will work (ex: i will see hello from backend )

then i visited the frontend => it will work ( i will see the front end)

now if i tried to vist again the backend, i will be redirected directly to the front end ) , and i will not be able to visit the backend only if removed the cookies from Chrome

```
    Timeout 2400
ProxyTimeout 2400
ProxyBadHeader Ignore

LogLevel debug
#SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
#RewriteLogLevel 3

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"

    ServerAdmin mail
    ServerName  link
    ServerAlias alias

    ProxyRequests Off
    LimitRequestBody 0
    Header unset Set-Cookie
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"



    ## APPS ##

    #BackEnd#
    ProxyPass /api http://10.102.135.11
    ProxyPassReverse  /api http://10.102.135.11


    #FrontEnd#
    ProxyPass / http://10.102.135.16/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://10.102.135.16/


</VirtualHost>
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem with registerServiceWorker of create-react-app and not HTTPD, it register automatically caches localy
so i had to desactivate it